# How to add a link to a website with a button and get back to the app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I was wondering how to add a link to a website so that when the user taps on a button, he will be taken to that webpage, but can then hit an x in the top left corner or hit the home button and then it will take them back to their app. I want it to be like iad where it doesn't close your app when you click on that link.

Comment: MSgambel is correct. Embedding your own web browser is the only way not be be thrown to the background and ultimately forcing your patron to find your app again to get back.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement your own [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in your app which will display the link, and handle all of the navigation. There are many tutorials on the web. Hope that Helps!

Comment: The concept being that you never actually need to leave the app

Comment: @XenElement: Yes, good point. I didn't think to mention that!